# document.location.href resets global variables

Tags: javascript, html, variables, global, reset

I am writing a game and use different html files but only one javascript file, which is included in every html file. I have my global variables in this file that are necessary for the game run. I have access and can change the variables from all over the html files which I am switching with , but for one thing I use javascript to change the page, because I need to differ either the game is over or a new round starts.

I use

```
if (...) {document.location.href = "end.html"}
else {document.location.href = "newround.html}
```

The changing actually works, but the thing is that after this change it resets ALL global variables in the JavaScript file, which is bad because I need some of those in the new rounds.. I cannot find anything helpful on the web, so please help me out, I really need this! :(

Thanks!

Comment: That's how page navigation works. JavaScript state is reset with every page load.

Comment: to work around it you can "save" the settings by sending HTTP parameters when you redirect to a different page

Comment: So how can I get a conditional href without resetting my global variables? :/

Answer (score 2):

What Matt said is right. If you want to preserve state between pages:

1. Put your changes in the URL parameters
2. In Cookies
3. Use the HTML5 local store
4. Store server side (this may not work since you're serving HTML pages)

Comment: Sorry if I am wrong, but won't the player need internet connection for that? I the unconditional href with <a href="x.html"> doesn't reset the global variables, so isn't there any way to implement an conditional href without resetting the variables? :/

Comment: Oh sorry, I'm dumb. :)
Well I have tried localStorage.setItem and localStorage.getItem (I assume that's what you meant with local store) and it even resets this one.. Once again: it is "document.location.href = "answerquestion.html";" what resets all variables (and local storage lol)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iframe` as game container.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I had issues with this too.
My workaround ended up being that I had to save the changed variables server-side.
I utilize a session manager (Redis) to save the last saved variables. 
When the page directs to "end.html" or "newround.html", recall the last saved variables.